# When a technology has significant changes should the tag be renamed? Azure-data-factory in this case

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

The tag [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory) indicates azure data factory v1, now superseded by data factory v2 (which has it's own tag: [azure-data-factory-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory-2)).

V2 (as the version indicates!) is a major new release. Although the [feature comparison page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/compare-versions) indicates what seems to be subtle changes, in practice the gotchas are very different.

Should [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory) be renamed to [azure-data-factory-v1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory-v1)?
However if taking this approach it would mean all tags would change regularly and be a nightmare to maintain. In this particular example the development methodology has also changed dramatically as data factory 2 is now primarily a UI driven development tool.

Or rather than renaming should the community simply use the date of publishing to derive the context? And instead the v2 tag disappear into disuse as V1 of data factory becomes no longer used.

Comment: In my opinion this tag should stay as azure-data-factory, reason behind this is because v1,v2,v3... etc are ways to indicate a change in the version of something. If you would actually go around renaming every tag after their version release every tag would be properly screwed cause it defeats the whole purpose of actually having tags. You are not going to remake/rename a tag like php to : php 4, php 5 etc. Version changes are something to take account into the documentation not in the title.

Comment: Agreed, should we create a new azure-data-factory-v1 to explicitly tag new questions regarding the old version?

Comment: I do not see any use in that, I expect people to upgrade and if not then they would have to specify they are using the old version. Having more tags would just be messy. Using my old example, you do not expect people to have a tag saying php7. Tags are updated and If people that use v1 do not read up on the tag changes then thats their own fault on not specifying they have v1 right? I do not see why we should mouth feed users to select what version they are actually using.

Comment: Ah sorry what I mean not for moderators to tag new posts with v1, but creating a new v1 tag to allow the question opener the option to use it?

Comment: And that is exactly what i said was not that good of an idea

Comment: Related: [Request to merge tags \[azure-data-factory-2\] with \[azure-data-factory\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401184/1478931)

Comment: I've marked this as [status-declined], since we've actually now merged [azure-data-factory-2] into the main [azure-data-factory] tag as of this more recent proposal: [Microsoft Azure Collective launch and proposed tag changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423231/1478931)