# Request to merge tags [azure-data-factory-2] with [azure-data-factory]

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

- There are 2,716 questions tagged [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory)
- There are 1,406 questions tagged [azure-data-factory-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory-2)
- There are 743 questions tagged [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory) and [azure-data-factory-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory-2)
- This means nearly **52%** of all [azure-data-factory-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory-2) questions are also tagged with [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory)

---

**Update:** Azure Data Factory questions are posted by using [azure-data-factory-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory-2) and [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory) to be more consistent can we use only one tag called [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory) instead of [azure-data-factory-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory-2).

Please check the tag description:

Questions tagged [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory)

Microsoft Azure Data Factory is a cloud service used to invoke (orchestrate) other Azure services in a controlled way using the concept of time slices. Data factories are predominately developed using hand crafted JSON, this provides the tool with instructions on what activities to perform. While still in preview, the introduction of Azure Data Factory V2 allows for an easier data integration experience using the api and not only JSON files.

Questions tagged [azure-data-factory-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory-2)

Microsoft Azure's cloud data integration service, it can compose data storage, movement, and processing services into automated data pipelines. It can connect to a wide variety of sources, not only from Azure. Its version 2 features more graphic tools and SDKs, providing an easier user experience compared to its previous version.

---

As the versions increases it will increase the number of tags in SO. Why can't we have a single tag in this case.

**Note:** Azure Data Factory has [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory) tag in Microsoft Q&A.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/azure-data-factory.html

---

I don't have permission to create synonyms for the product called Azure Data Factory.

I have spotted two separate tags related to the Azure Data Factory service:

It has been tracked with [azure-data-factory-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory-2) and [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory).

Could you please merge [azure-data-factory-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory-2) with [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory)?

[image: failed to propose synonym error]

Comment: Why? One seems to be for version 2. You should explain why we don't need to distinguish between version 1 and version 2.

Comment: Please, use the proper tag formatting with `[tag:` prefix, so we all can easily go to the tag info page. Tangentially related: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265844/should-i-not-use-the-generic-tag-if-my-solution-is-limited-to-a-specific-version), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262823/wouldnt-tag-inheritance-make-sense?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: As already mentioned, please do update the post to add sufficient information as to why you need to merge a version specific tag with a generic one. See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385573/4099593) for an example request.

Comment: @RobertLongson Well, not speaking for the OP here, but there seem to be many different features between the two. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @RobertLongson, version 1 is deprecated. To be more consistent tags why can't azure-data-factory-2 replaced with azure-data-factory.  To be more consistent tags across all the community channel I would suggest to have only only one tag called azure-data-factory instead of azure-data-factory-2.

Comment: 1. deprecated != nobody will ever ask questions about it ever again 2. if we merge everything then we're going to point people to answers about the deprecated version without any signal that it's deprecated.

Comment: @RobertLongson By that logic, We're going to have many many versions tags for each deprecated version- Most of which will be useless or unnecessary segregate questions common to both versions. Segregation of questions is especially relevant in a small tag like azureudata-factory. deprecated === "No one should ever ask questions about  that version again OR if they ask, they should make clear that they're using the deprecated version in the body of the post and not the tag".

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT Some stats will help make your case like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385573/)

Comment: @TheMaster I expect it would be exceptionally rare for someone writing a question to indicate in the question body that it's about a deprecated version in the body of the post. I've never seen it in all the posts I've read as far as I can remember.

Comment: @TheMaster updated the question with the tag description. Which says the same.

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT Need Stats(see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399396))- as in how many questions were tagged in each tag and what **harm** does the split do? You should be willing to fight tooth and nail and show that it is indeed bad and causes actual harm. 1. Stats, 2. Subject matter experts quotes/support from other users of the tag(in the form of answers) will help a long way(Consider inviting them). If you're satisfied with the final format, ping the moderator Bhargav to  consider removing [meta-tag:status-declined] and to consider the  synonym request.

Comment: @BhargavRao Could you consider removing  [status-declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-declined) and to consider the synonym request

Comment: Related: [When a technology has significant changes should the tag be renamed? Azure-data-factory in this case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371914/1478931) (which discusses the idea of renaming the [azure-data-factory] tag to [azure-data-factory-v1] instead)

Comment: This merger + synonym is now complete, as of a more recent (and broader) proposal that includes this suggestion: [Microsoft Azure Collective launch and proposed tag changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423231/1478931)